# List all numbers from 1 to n that are not multiples of 3 without using print or display

Tags: programming

```
n=100

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, If[Mod[i, 4] != 0, Print[i]]]
```

I have tried this but I don't want print or display. I cannot think of any other way of solving this. Is there another alternate solution?

Comment: There are lot of alternate solutions, but this one works as well (restart your kernel).  Look up Table and Divisible. *Are you really sure this is not something that you are supposed to solve on your own?*

Comment: See  ...  `Table`

Comment: Try `Complement[Range[100], 3 Range[33]]` to list all numbers that are not divisible by 3. (I also don't understand where your `Mod 4` condition comes from.)

Comment: Usually smth like `Drop[Range@100, {3, 100, 3}]`

Comment: `Select[Range@100, Mod[#, 3] != 0 &]`

Comment: `Cases[n_ /; Divisible[n, 3]]@Range@100`